# Hausdorff and Compact under different topology.

Tags: general-topology

> $X$ is compact under $\mathcal T$ and is Hausdorff under $\mathcal S$. If $\mathcal T \subset\mathcal S$ then $\mathcal T= \mathcal S.$

It's my question. But I think it's incorrect. Not $T \subset\mathcal S$, but $\mathcal S \subset \mathcal T$.

Because if $X=[0,1]$, $\mathcal T$ = usual topology, $\mathcal S$ = lower limit topology, then $(X,\mathcal T)$ is compact and $(X,\mathcal S)$ is Hausdorff and $\mathcal T \subset\mathcal S$ but $\mathcal T \neq\mathcal S$.

Are you agree with me? Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Does this help: [Maximality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_Topology_is_Maximally_Compact)

Comment: Did you hear about 'chaotic' and 'deterministic'.. heh-hehe ^^

Comment: Yes, you are right (simpler example: let $S$ and $T$ be the discrete and trivial (indiscrete) topology, respectively, on any $X$ with at least two points)